# Creating gMSA for Azure AD Domain Services without PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword does not seem to work

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD Domain Services domain and need to create a gMSA (group managed service account).

I am using the sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory-domain-services/create-gmsa with my domain name:

```
# Create a new custom OU on the managed domain
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "MyNewOU" -Path "DC=CONTOSO100,DC=COM"

# Create a service account 'WebFarmSvc' within the custom OU.
New-ADServiceAccount -Name WebFarmSvc  `
-DNSHostName ` WebFarmSvc.contoso100.com  `
-Path "OU=MYNEWOU,DC=CONTOSO100,DC=com"  `
-KerberosEncryptionType AES128, AES256  ` -ManagedPasswordIntervalInDays 30  `
-ServicePrincipalNames http/WebFarmSvc.contoso100.com/contoso100.com, `
http/WebFarmSvc.contoso100.com/contoso100,  `
http/WebFarmSvc/contoso100.com, http/WebFarmSvc/contoso100
```

The sample code also includes:

```
-PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword CONTOSO-SERVER$
```

I don't know what I have to put inside here and the Microsoft Doc doesn't say how it got the 'CONTOSO-SERVER$' object. So I ignore it.

If I ignore it the creation seems to succeed. After that I see my gMSA in my Organisational Unit in Active Directoy Users and Computers.

[image]

But when I test the account, I get
[image]

So it seems the PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword is important. How can I get this to work using Azure AD Domain Services?

Comment: Actually Microsoft explains exactly what `PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword` is for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a group manually in my new Organisational Unit, added the Host to it and rebooted my host.

Only then Test-ADServiceAccount WebFarmSvc succeeded:
[image]